# TVML / tvOS : Template background?

Tags: javascript, html, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

so i've been working with the Apple TV for a few days. I ran into a little problem with the templates.

For example the [catalogTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/CatalogTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH35-SW2) is limited in its usage. I want to change the background. How could i approach this? I know you can change the background-color with rgb blabla , but that is only for an element as it says.

Is there a way to change the color of the standard grey-ish background? Or even load a picture? Or is it possible to make a transparant picture that is layered over the template?

The only way i see it working is, taking the customizable [divTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/DivTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH28-SW1) and building exactly the same as the catalogTemplate and then change the background. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by just adding the below code snippet. Hope it helps someone.

```
<catalogTemplate>
    <background>
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1:9002/images/black-background.png"/>
    </background>
</catalogTemplate>
```